# Number of elements $g$ such that $g^{20}=e$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I need some help. I tried to answer the following exercise:

If $G$ is a cyclic group and $15$ divides the order of $G$ determine the number of $g \in G$ that are a solution to the equation $g^{15}=e$. If $20$ divides the group order determine the number of solutions $g^{20}=e$. Generalise.

Here is what I thought:

Since $G$ is cyclic we know that for every divisor of $|G|$ there is exactly one subgroup of this order. If $g$ is a generator of $G$ then $g^{|G|\over 15}$ is a generator of the subgroup of order $15$.

Any element of order $15, 5, 3$ or $1$ satisfies $g^{15}=e$ and also, every such element is contained in $\langle g^{|G|\over 15} \rangle$. In fact, every element in this subgroup satisfies the given equation.

Since $\langle g^{|G|\over 15}\rangle$ contains $15$ elements the number of elements satisfying the equation is $15$.

By the same reasoning the answer to $g^{20}=e$ should be $20$ and the answer to $x^n=e$ should be $n$.

But then to check my answer I tried to count the elements of each order.

For $15$ I got

$$ \begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{order}    & 1& 3& 5& 15 \\
\# \text{elems} & 1& 2& 4& 8 
\end{array}$$

So in this case my claim is confirmed as these sum up to $15$. But then I counted the elements in the case $n=20$:
$$ \begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{order}    & 1& 2& 4& 5 & 20 \\
\# \text{elems} & 1& 1& 2& 4 & 8
\end{array}$$

And these sum up to $16$. Something is wrong somewhere but I can't see the mistake.

> Please could someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: $10$ divides $20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the elements of order $10$.

Comment: Oh right, of course, thank you! And is the claim that there are $n$ elements with $x^n = e$ correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.